# Is Declaring a Meta-Class-Type for a Templatized Method an Error?

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, metaprogramming, compiler-bug

I think I have found a bug in gcc, but I'd like confirmation:

```
struct Foo {
    void good(int);

    template <typename T>
    void bad(T);
};
```

All of the following work fine:

- `enable_if_t<is_same_v<decltype(&Foo::good), void (Foo::*)(int)>, void> test1() {}`
- `template <typename T> enable_if_t<is_same_v<decltype(&T::good), void (T::*)(int)>, void> test2() {}`
- `enable_if_t<is_same_v<decltype(&Foo::bad<int>), void (Foo::*)(int)>::value, void> test3() {}`
- `template <typename T> enable_if_t<is_same_v<decltype(&Foo::bad<T>), void (Foo::*)(T)>, void> test4() {}`

But this cannot even be defined:

```
template <typename T>
enable_if_t<is_same_v<decltype(&T::bad<int>), void (T::*)(int)>, void> test5() {}
```

If it is I get several errors starting with:

> error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 2)

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://ideone.com/6qKW4w)

Can anyone confirm this is a gcc bug? It seems to work on other compilers, such as Visual Studio: http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/, but using http://melpon.org/wandbox I can confirm that this persists through gcc 7.0.

Comment: Clang gives me a nice error: *error: use 'template' keyword to treat 'bad' as a dependent template name* - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords

Comment: @chris Yup, that was the issue. Wonder why Visual Studio doesn't require this. And I wonder why gcc isn't more helpful. You wanna post that as an answer?

Comment: @chris Should that be required? It seems pretty clear what I'm calling without it.

Comment: `T::bad` looks like a dependent context to me. Without knowing what `T` is, we can't know what `bad` is, similar to the example in the answer of the link with `t::f`. The question is probably better as a duplicate than answered with a duplicate answer. However, I don't know why VS wouldn't require the keyword. Perhaps the ongoing parsing improvements to support two-phase lookup will make this fix easier.